# text appearance doesn't work inside my theme

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

I'm trying to put a style in all my app, so i created a theme with my style inside :

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/subtitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="subtitle parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/purple</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But `textAppearance` doesn't work it stay the same, but when i put something like `textColor` in my theme, it works

Comment: Which device are you testing on? OS ?

Comment: On Android 4.0.3. (Samsung galaxy tab2 10.1 by the way)

Answer (score 10):

This is a quite old question, but the answer may help someone.
The key to solving this is in the "precedence order of styling techniques" here: 
[image: precedenceOrderOfDifferentStylingTechniquesImage]

on the top is the highest precedence, at the bottom is the lowest precedence.

As we can see, `theme` has the lowest precedence. In your example, your `android:textAppearance` property is being overridden by the `default style` of every view that accepts this attribute.

The default style property is defined in every them for every specific view that accepts this attribute: in this case `android:Theme.Holo.Light` provides the default style for textView as `android:textViewStyle`... for buttons is `android:buttonStyle` (which inherits its `textAppearance` from TextView), and so on.

So if you are trying to apply that `android:textAppearance`  property to a TextVew you should use  `<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/subtitle</item>` instead of `<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/subtitle</item>` inside `MyTheme`. A way to verify this is setting `android:textViewStyle` to null, that way your current code will work fine with textViews `<item name="android:textViewStyle">null</item>`

This post explains this precedence a bit deeper:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is, you have not declared the color in your xml for theme. Please add the following line within the `<resources>` and try. Your xml will look like:

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/subtitle</item>
</style>

 <color name="purple">code for your color</color>

<style name="subtitle parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/purple</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
</style>
```

I think this will do.

Comment: it doesn't work, but the color purple i already declared it somewhere else (colors.xml)

Comment: try doing it this way and check if does?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your target API you need to put your customization code in different /res/values-vxx/style.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

For TextView, try `android:textAppearanceSmall` inside your theme instead.